# Get Jenkins credentials usage list - groovy script

Tags: jenkins-plugins, credentials

As a Jenkins admin, i would like to clean unused credentials from the Jenkins. Is it possible to run some groovy script in the Script Console so the output will be:

```
CRED: job1, job2 ...
```

Or some other readable format so we could see stored creds usage.

Comment: you can start with - https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/list-credential.groovy , and do the relevant modifications

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking how to retrieve creds from jobs.

Comment: if you want to see which creds are in use , you can do it manually via the UI.

but if you a lot of credentials it will take some time. ..

Comment: meanwhile, running a grep command on /var/lib/jenkins/**/config.xml with a ID can do the job, bu I have to run the command on all IDs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getFingerprintOf() method from CredentialsProvider. Here's a sample code which does exactly what you need:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials;

def creds = CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      Credentials.class
);

for (c in creds) {
  fp = CredentialsProvider.getFingerprintOf(c);
  println(c.id + " : " + fp.getJobs());
}
```

But if you need to experiment with other methods, you can refer them in the java docs here: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Fingerprint.html?is-external=true

Comment: I tried running this script in Jenkins console, and it complains `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getJobs() on null object`

Comment: If a set of credentials hasn't been used by a job yet, then the fingerprint will return NULL. Changing the code to this makes the script work: 
    `for (c in jenkinsCredentials) {
      Fingerprint fp = CredentialsProvider.getFingerprintOf(c);
      if (fp != null) {
        println(c.id + " : " + fp.getJobs() + "\n");
      }
      else {
        println(c.id + " : Not Used\n");
       }
    }`

Comment: @sunflower_fields_forever,  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getJobs() on null object` can be avoided with `fp?.getJobs()`